# Paypal Buy Now button for multiple items

Tags: paypal

I want to add a buy now button to my website. I already have a cart system and I need to send all the items to checkout with Paypal buy now button.
A few years back I remember using the buy button with a form and I could set multiple items by  specifying multiple hidden inputs like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="item name 1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="item name 2">
...
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_n" value="item name n">
```

Now with the new buy button JS API I can't seem to do that anymore.
Am I missing something here? How can I add a buy button for multiple items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use an HTML form to create the buttons and use the Upload command.

The JavaScript buttons aren't currently available to work with the Upload command unless you modify the associated JavaScript file. The Mini-Cart does kind of use the Upload feature. If you want to take a look at that it may offer you the functionality you're after. There should be a link to it from the "PayPal payment buttons" page.

Comment: Yeah I did eventually found the HTML form button at the Paypal website.

Comment: I might try the mini cart, but I don't think I'll use it in my current project

Comment: The Mini-Cart is pretty cool. It's been around for awhile and is very stable. It's worth testing to see if you can use it in future projects.

Comment: What was the solution? I also want to know.